# Heapq in Python3 not working with tuples since it's not pop with the expectation order

Tags: python, heapq

Everyone says if you push tuple into `heapq`, it will take the first argument as the comparison factor.

But it's not! I'm curious what's wrong in my code?

```
for task_name, counter in tasks_counter.items():
    heappush(tasks_q, (-int(counter), task_name, counter))
heapify(tasks_q)
while tasks_q:
    print(tasks_q.pop())
```

## output

```
(-1, 'G', 1)
(-1, 'F', 1)
(-1, 'E', 1)
(-1, 'D', 1)
(-1, 'C', 1)
(-1, 'B', 1)
(-6, 'A', 6)
```

I think I should get the item with value `A` first, right?
But it's not.

Any alternative solution to use built-in priority queue with Python?

## Another example's output.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You are using the `pop` function of `list`.  You need to use [`heapq.heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop) function instead.  It will adjust the list to maintain the heap invariant along the way.  See the [Basic Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples).

It's also not necessary to call `heapify` if you start with `[]` and call `heappush` repeatedly.  `heappush` already ensures that the heap invariant is maintained.